# In pandas, what is an ideal way to use regex to keep substrings in a series where there is a match otherwise keep the existing string?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with a series I'd like to edit. There is a pattern in some of the strings such as this : `<a class="authors-detail__display-name" href="/staff/nathan-smith/">Nathan Smith</a>'.`

My regex pattern `(?<=>)(.*?)(?=<)` matches anything between '>' and '<'. I'd like to edit and return the string match for rows where this pattern exists. In other rows I'd like to do nothing if the pattern matches nothing.

What's an ideal way to handle this problem in pandas?

`data['author'].str.findall(("(?<=>)(.*?)(?=<)"))` returns a boolean item for matches, is this the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace won't help you since you are not replacing with a
known value, you have to use extract. Use data.dropna() to remove NaN values

#Code:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'author': ['<a class="authors-detail__display-name" href="/staff/nathan-smith/">Nathan Smith</a>',
'<a class="authors-detail__display-name" href="/staff/nathan-smith" />', 
'<a class="authors-detail__display-name" href="/staff/nathan-smith/">James Great</a>']})
print(data)

data['author'] = data['author'].str.extract('.*[>](.*?)[<].*', expand=True)
print(data)
```

#Output:

```
                                              author
0  <a class="authors-detail__display-name" href="...
1  <a class="authors-detail__display-name" href="...
2  <a class="authors-detail__display-name" href="...
         author
0  Nathan Smith
1           NaN
2   James Great
```